# Enumerated Swiping in Swift

Tags: swift

So I have this for in function where I enumerate to print buttons

```
 for (index, answer) in model.answers.enumerated() {
        print(index)

        let answerLabel = UILabel()
        answerLabel.text = answer

        answersStack.addArrangedSubview(answerLabel)

        let answerButton = UIButton()
        answerButton.tag = index
        let imageNormal = UIImage(named: "circle_empty")
        answerButton.setImage(imageNormal, for: .normal)
        let imageSelected = UIImage(named: "circle_filled")
        answerButton.setImage(imageSelected, for: .selected)
        answerButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        answerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        answersStack.addArrangedSubview(answerButton)

    }
}
```

At first, it looks like the first picture, but then when I swipe the collection view a couple times it looks like the second picture. I have a feeling it has something to do with the enumerated function but I am not sure why. Some help on this question would be greatly appreciated! - Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you place that loop?

Comment: in an extension

Answer (score 0):

Collection views reuse cells, so you'll need to remove all of the answers from your `answersStack` before adding the new ones

```
let views = answersStack.arrangedSubviews
for view in views {
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}

for (index, answer) in model.answers.enumerated() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: There just one problem with this, and that is that when you swipe now it doesn't duplicate, but when you pick an answer and then go back the selection of what you chose goes away. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @josh You will need to save the selected answers somewhere, and then set the button.isSelected value in your for loop

Comment: Like how would it work? Your response ASAP would be appriecated.